# xcode 7 not displaying data in parse table view in simulator, but works in device

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview, xcode7-beta5

I'm using Parse's table view class, I have my custom cell for the table view, everything worked fine in Xcode 6.3.2. 
I just updated my Xcode to 7 beta, because I want to run tests on my device without paying 100$ for developer account, anyways, the parse table view isn't displaying the data in table view:
[image: screenshot of the table-view]

When actually when I try to print my query results to the console, I do get my results.
Here's my code for the controller incharged for this view:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class MeetsTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "Meets";
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true;
    self.textKey="city";
    self.paginationEnabled = false;

}

// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func  queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Meets");
    query.orderByDescending("numberOfComming");
    return query;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! CarTableViewCell!;

    if cell == nil {
        cell = CarTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "MyCell");
    }
    if let cityName = object?["city"] as? String{
        cell?.meetName?.text = "מפגש ב\(cityName)";
    }
    if let address = object?["address"] as? String{
        cell?.meetAddress?.text = address;
    }
    if let date = object?["date"] as? String{
        cell?.meetDate?.text = date;
    }
    if let time = object?["time"] as? String{
        cell?.meetTime?.text = time;
    }
    if let people = object?["numberOfComming"] as? Int{
        cell?.peopleAttending?.text = "\(people)";
    }
    print(object); // console is printing query results successfully

    if let thumbnail = object?["meetImg"] as? PFFile {

        thumbnail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (imageData, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.meetImage.image = image
            }}
    }

    return cell;
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

I just tried to run the app in my device, and the table is working like it should be, just the simulator isn't showing the data.

Comment: reset simulator content and check

Comment: I am facing same problem seems like bug in xcode, have you found any solution

Comment: I posted out this question in apple's dev forum, but there was no answer over there as well. Since September 16th, Xcode 7 is officially released, you can try download that and check, i haven't downloaded it yet.
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

Comment: Maybe this is the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041855/uitableview-empty-with-ios-9-beta-5-update/32052154#32052154

Comment: I will try it and let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If data is loading on your device and not the simulator, it could be an issue of not simulating a location, which could prevent your query from pull results to populate the table view.
If this may be the case, you can simulate a location through the following options: 
1) Xcode -> Debug -> Simulate Location (see screenshot below) by selecting one of the cities or adding a GPX file to your project.
2) Simulator -> Debug -> Location (see screenshot below).
 3) You can also set your location via Maps on Simulator (see: http://apple.co/1JtnYIv).

[image]

[image]