# UITableView Empty with iOS 9 beta 5 update

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, ios9, xcode7

After updating to Xcode 7 and then the iOS 9 beta 5 on my iPhone, none of my UITableViews are displaying data, except one. They are all downloading information from my Parse database, and the one that works, is downloading everything perfectly for one section of the table, but not the other. The other 3 table views download the information, and calculate the correct number of rows, however nothing is being displayed. I tried just displaying static text for all cells, however it is not even displaying that.

Any clue of what is going on? I don't think it is a problem with downloading the Parse data, but actually displaying it onto the tableviews.

```
 let cell:MyChinupsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! MyChinupsTableViewCell

    if namesArray.count > 0 {
        cell.nameLabel.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.bodyText.text = chinUpsArray[indexPath.row]
        let count = likesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.likeCount.text = "♥︎ " + String(count)

    }

    return cell
```

It is another table view, but it still gets the point across. Unless I am missing something, everything is in the correct hierarchy here. 
[image]

I added that label as a test, and that is not appearing as well...

[image]

This is what it looks like in the view debugger. As you see, it correctly downloaded the correct amount of rows... 2 Thank You's and 4+ conversations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can't say if this is a universal solution, but in the exact same scenario (tablviewcell content empty at runtime after updating to XCode 7 beta 5) this solved it for me:

I had to go through every single item inside the content view (including all constraints) and tick the checkbox "Installed" in the properties inspector. Initially only wR hR was checked.

[image]

Comment: OMG You are a life saver. This fixed everything!!!!!! I am so glad it was such a simple fix. You are amazing.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem in iOS 9.1.
If you're only developing for one device family per storyboard, try unchecking "Use Size Classes" in the file inspector of the storyboard. It solved it for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happens really often after each update of iOS, that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't work well anymore.

You should try setting :

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = XX;
self.tableView.rowHeight = XX;
```

and see if it helps.

**2nd answer:**

Are your `nameLabel` added to `contentView` of your cell or the cell directly ? It should be `contentView`.

Comment: Okay, I just tried that and it did not work. The heights seem to be working correctly, they seem to be exactly the same size as before the update.

Comment: So cells are here but not the content ?
Could you give the code on how you fill the cells ?

Comment: Cells all load, and the data is loading completely (I have printlns) to prove this. I will update the original question with some code. That code prints nothing to the screen. I tried it with static data, like `cell.nameLabel.text = "Test"` and this also does not print anything to the screen.

Comment: They are in the Content View of the Custom Table View Cell called MyChinupsTableViewCell. This was all working completely right before the update to iOS 9 / Xcode 7. And what is weird is that only one of the table views in my app work, and the rest don't. The one that works perfectly is the one with the most code attached...

Comment: Did you try coloring background of contentView of your cells, so you can check if they at least display it ?

Comment: Yes, they display the background color, just no text. And they display the exact amount of cells that are supposed to load.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the cells view hierarchy, check in view debugger. use `bringsubviewtofront` if they are behind

Comment: So, in the view debugger, it showed dozens of different layers. Was it supposed to show the labels and textviews as well there? Because it didn't show any of that, just showed the content views.

Comment: I added a picture to show you the view debugger. What does that tell you?

Comment: Looks proper. try changing dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier with some thing different, May sounds weird but it fixed my issue once.

Comment: That did not work :( I know all the information is there because when I click on the cell, it brings me to the correct screen! I just can't figure out for the life of me why it isn't displaying the info. I might have to just recreate the view controller, which I have been trying to avoid...

Comment: If in case, you have any constraints that might be broken?

Comment: There are no broken constraints that I see at this time.

Answer (score 0):

For my fix I had to find the problematic subview through trial and error of removing each until the issue went away. I don't know exactly what the issue was but after creating a new subview it works now. Absolutely zero warnings or errors generated.