# UITableViewCell not displaying contents in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7-beta5

I updated Xcode to the new version 7 for ios 9 apps. my app before had these custom cells and they had labels in them and they had a data source and it worked but when i run the app and the table view shows the cells they are empty without the labels. however, when i click on the space where one should be it turns highlighted and goes to the next screen for when it is tapped. this is so weird so, i check all the alpha involved with the labels and they seem fine.

Comment: help? please? anyone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32052154/4151918

Comment: thanks dude you rock