# Table View issues in IOS9 using AutoLayouts (wCompact hRegular)

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uistoryboard, ios9

I run my existing project in Xcode 7 beta(iOS 9) where no data is visible in the table view which works perfect in iOS8 and showing the data.It is completely showing blank in iOS9. Coming to UI design i used Autolayouts with particular width and particular height ie..wCompact||hRegular (only for iPhone portrait) on the storyboard.

Is there any Autolayouts issues in iOS9?
Is there any conflicts by taking wCompact hRegular for designing in iOS9?

I will be very thankful for the quick answers.

Comment: It may be worthwhile providing screenshots of your storyboard showing the delegate/datasource outlet connections and/or relevant code.

Comment: @SteveWilford thanks for the response, delegate and datasource connections are good, its working fine in iOS8, I think here most stressable point is Autolayouts.

Comment: @RameshBabuPatnala Here is the great solution, i too faced same issue, but now its working good Reference link  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32052154/1942683

Comment: @srinadh , working great....perfect solution, thank you!!!!!