# Why SubViews of UIView not showing when View is opening in iOS 9 only with XCODE7

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios9, xcode7

I am getting problem with showing a UIView when a push is found in app.My View has label and button and all thing was running good. Even right now it is running good in earlier iOS versions except iOS9.

I have made this view using XIB and adding it on window.

[image]

I have a class that link this XIB-

```
 #import "MyViewPop.h"

   @implementation MyViewPop

 - (id)init {

  self = [super  init];

       if (self) {
           self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewPop" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
           self.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds; 
           }
  return self;

 }
```

and i am opening it at when Push is arrived-

```
MyViewPop*  pushp= [[MyViewPop alloc] init];

UIWindow *w = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window];
pushp.tag=1000000;
[w addSubview:pushp];
[w makeKeyAndVisible];
```

But only myViewPop is open but I am not seeing added button and label over there.

I do not know why this type of bug is with is and Xcode7 even the same code is running very good for opening my this view in iOS8,iOS7.

I have also another pop up in app and this is same copy of these all pop up but all other are running good in all iOS versions.

Please share your concern and help me if you have any ideas.

I have also gone through this suggesion - [UITableView Empty with iOS 9 beta 5 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041855/uitableview-empty-with-ios-9-beta-5-update) 
but It is only showing label and button in a very small in top left corner.