# Blank cells when running on ios 9.1 or 9.0 simulator, works fine on 8.4 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Cells are blank and xcode displays no error when running my app on ios simulator 9.1 or 9.0. Works fine on 8.4 simulator. There is no change to the code.

[image]

I have tried the following

1. Deleted the custom cell in the storyboard and recreated it. Didn't work
2. Changed the identifier and file name. Didn't work
3. Deleted the custom cell .h file from the project and then added it back. Didn't work
4. After the tableView is visible executed reloadData. Didn't work.
5. Disconnected then reconnected the tableView delegate and dataSource in the Storyboard. Didn't work.
6. Used the default `customCell.textLabel.text = [_nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];`  and imageView `customCell.imageView.image = [_profileImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];` properties in my custom cell. Worked but this doesn't help because I want to use my custom objects.
7. Hard coded customName, customTime, and customImage. `customCell.customName.text =@"hi";` and `customCell.customImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"commentButton.png"];`. Didn't work
8. I added breakpoints to the datasource methods and all breakpoints executed.
9. I used the NSLog to see if my customCell is nil. I am getting the following response from the log `<messagePreviewCell: 0x7fcdf8dd3860; ...>`.
10. I NSLog'ed the nameLabel before setting a value in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and it logs what is set in the storyboard.
11. I searched my code/storyboard for hidden commands, nothing is set as hidden.

The checkbox for "Use Sizes Classes" is checked and I have set the size to "wCompact hAny".

My code for the cellForRowAtIndexPath found in the viewcontroller.m

```
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"messagePreviewCell";

    messagePreviewCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    customCell.customName.text = [_nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    customCell.customTime.text = [_timeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    customCell.customDescription.text = [_messageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSString *className = [[[_profileImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] class] description];

    if ([className isEqualToString:@"UIImage"]) {
        customCell.customImage.image = [_profileImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }

    return customCell;
```

My code was running fine...Please help, thank you!

Comment: If you hardcode the labels texts, the cells remains empty? ex: `customCell.customName.text = @"HELLOOO";`

Comment: check your datasource//_nameArray or _timeArray.. do a hardcode on labels

Comment: did you wire (create IBOutlets) the customName/customType/customDescription labels from the storyboard to your code?

Comment: A good thing to do at this point might be to add a breakpoint in a few of your data source methods. Then check:

1. Are they getting called.
2. Is the cell you are dequeueing nil.
3. Are your `nameArray`, `timeArray` and `messageArray`'s nil?
4. Are the labels on the cell nil.
5. Is anything on the cell hidden via opacity or the hidden property.

Comment: Are you using size classes?

Answer (score 0):

If your only developing for one device family uncheck "Use Size Classes" in the file inspector of the storyboard.

Found my answer here (additional info)!
[UITableView Empty with iOS 9 beta 5 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041855/uitableview-empty-with-ios-9-beta-5-update)