# UITableView doesn't fill custom cells inside of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have UITabBarController and on one of the tabs I have UIViewController with UITableView inside.

I had created custom cell class.

If I fill tableView custom cells without UITabBarController (I put entry point to UIViewController) everything works fine, but if I use UITabBarController firstly, my cells are not populated with any data when I reach UITableView tab.
Where could be a bug here?

```
import UIKit

class blaViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! blaTableViewCell
        cell.myLabel.text = "123"
        return cell
    }
}

import UIKit

class blaTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try tick install checkbox for all the constraints, not only wh wr. It worked for me. It is also described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052154/2064500

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped to save a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
```

Try to do strong variable

```
@IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help